# Using compression to reduce the size of a xodus store

Tags: xodus

Is it possible to use some level of compression on a xodus store/environment/entities?

I have seen it's possible to encrypt a store. But I haven't seen anything related to compressing a store.

Comment: Please add some examples that you've already tried

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Hi and welcome to [so]! Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store encryption is added due to security reasons. Xodus itself tries to store data in an optimal way. Some large portion of data like files/blobs can be stored compressed (zipped) programmatically. You can use VirtualFileSystem for storing large portion of data in a transactional safe way. There is `VirtualFileSystem#setCustomConverter` for using your own implementation for modifying input/output steams. Check [how it used](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/master/vfs/src/test/java/jetbrains/exodus/vfs/VfsStressTestsWithSnappyCompression.java) in tests for Snappy compression

Comment: Thanks for the answer.